# Jqgrid client side sorting not working from ID=10

Tags: jqgrid

I am encountering a wierd problem while implementing the client side sorting on jqgrid.

The sorting works fine till the Id is in range of 1 to 9 but when it encounters the Id 10 instead of placing the Id 10 at the last position it is placing it in the second position.

any idea what the problem is???

The id column is like this

```
ID
1
10
2
3
4 
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

in your colModel you should define **sorttype: 'number'** for column ID.